# Database Design - "special" entry in one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design

Let's say I have two tables in a one-to-many relationship.  We'll call the first one Bros, and the second one Homies.  A bro can have multiple homies, but only one of which can be his 'main man'.

(Look; examples are hard. Don't yell at me.)

How would I represent that?  I could put a 'main_man' entry into the bros table, but that would duplicate entries I'd have in the homies table.

I could also put an entry in the homies table, but that wouldn't restrict other homies from being the main man.

Is there a proper way to do this?  Would it be easier to just do it a wrong way and handle it with the application instead?

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of options to modeling this.

Firstly, does a `main_man` also have to be a `homie`?  If so, I'd add a flag on the `homies` table. MySQL datatypes are little imperfect, but I'd use a boolean, which we always map to a `TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'boolean'` datatype.

The next step is to restrict the values of this to either `1` or `NULL`, don't allow any other values. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't enforce CHECK constraints, so if we want the database to enforce this rule, we'd need to implement `BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE` triggers to enforce it.

Finally, we'd add a `UNIQUE` constraint

```
... ON homies (bro_id, main_man)
```

With that, MySQL will only allow a single row with a main_man value of `1` for each `bro_id`.

This is slight deviation from the normative pattern of NULL meaning "unknown", which I see espoused by the Microsoft documentation. In our implementation, we're using a NULL value to mean "no, not a main_man".  The primary advantage of allowing `NULL` values is that SQL (in general) and MySQL in particular does not consider a NULL value to be a "duplicate" of another NULL value. The UNIQUE constraint allows multiple rows with NULL value. (I think there's some SQL_MODE setting that changes this behavior, but we don't ever go there.)

To get just the `homies` that are a `main_man`...

```
WHERE main_man = 1
```

or, more concisely, since we're not using a zero to represent TRUE, and if we are certain that no other non-zero values might be present...

```
WHERE main_man
```

The other logic is pretty straightforward, check for `main_man IS NULL` or `MAIN_MAN <=> NULL`, `ORDER BY main_man, ...`, and return the `main_man` column in the `SELECT` if you want to sort it out on the client.

You might consider using a MySQL `ENUM` datatype instead, as long as we allow for NULL values, and we verify that MySQL will allow and enforce a UNIQUE constraint on an ENUM column. (I've never tried that before).

This is just one approach out of several, but it's one that I've successfully used in the past.

--

**DEMONSTRATION**

```
CREATE TABLE bro 
( id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE homie
( id         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
, bro_id     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref bros.id'
, main_man   TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'boolean, 1=is the main man'
, homie_name VARCHAR(10)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

ALTER TABLE homie
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX homie_UX1 (bro_id, main_man);

ALTER TABLE homie
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_homie_bro FOREIGN KEY (bro_id) REFERENCES bro (id);
```

TODO: add BEFORE INSERT/BEFORE UPDATE trigger to restrict value for `main_man` column.

Test this by adding some rows, and check that we can't have more than one `main_man` for a given `bro_id`.

```
INSERT INTO bro (id) VALUES 
(2),(3);

INSERT INTO homie (id, bro_id, main_man, homie_name) VALUES
  ( 11, 2, NULL, 'mr.slate' )
, ( 12, 2, 1, 'barney')
;

-- attempt to insert another main_man        
INSERT INTO homie (id, bro_id, main_man, homie_name) VALUES
  ( 13, 2, 1, 'wilma' )
;

-- Error Code: 1062
-- Duplicate entry '2-1' for key 'homie_UX1'

UPDATE homie SET main_man = 1 WHERE id = 11 ; 

-- Error Code: 1062
-- Duplicate entry '2-1' for key 'homie_UX1'
```

NOTE: I neglected to mention, as a small bonus, the `homie_UX1` index (created to enforce the `UNIQUE` constraint) also serves to support the foreign key, since bro_id is the leading column. That's why we added the index before we added the foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is a pretty standard way of modelling one-to-many relationship, where one of the child rows is considered "special":

[image]

This model has the following important properties:

- In addition to normal FK from child to parent, we also use a "reverse" FK from parent to child.
- We use *identifying relationship*, making the child a *weak entity* (i.e. child's key contains the key migrated from the parent). A bro is identified by the homie he belongs to **and** by his "number" (BRO_NO) within that particular homie. A different bro within different homie may have the same BRO_NO.

Taken together, these two properties ensure that:

- At most one child is special per each parent.<sup>1</sup>
- A parent cannot choose the special row outside of its own set of children - note how FK1 in HOMIE table spans not just MAIN_MAN_ID but HOMIE_ID as well.

However, in *concurrent environment*, you'll have to be careful how you generate BRO_NO. Some possibilities:

- Make it auto-increment and live with "holes" in the values.
- Lock the parent then use MAX + 1.
- Just use MAX + 1 without locking, but be prepared to handle key violation and retry INSERT if concurrent transaction attempted to insert the same value.

If there are other tables referencing BRO, you may consider adding a surrogate key (e.g. BRO_ID). For pros and cons of surrogate keys, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info).

BTW, there is a variation of the above model: lose the reverse FK and just consider whichever bro has the *smallest* BRO_NO as special. This is fine if you know the special bro in advance, or if you don't mind updating the key (and possibly cascading the change) to move a bro to the top.

---

*<sup>1</sup> If a DBMS supports deferred constraints, the FK in parent can be made non-NULL, and ensure **exactly** one child is special (and not just zero or one). Deffering one of the FKs breaks chicken-and-egg problem when inserting new data in the presence of circular FKs. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support deferred constraints.*